# index-error: string out of range in wordle similar game

Tags: python-3.x, index-error

So i'm making a Wordle clone and i keep getting a "indexerror: string is out of range" and i dont know what to do and every time i do the second guess it will say indexerrror string is out off range
at line 30

```
import random

def Wordle():
    
    position = 0
    clue = ""

    print("Welcome to Wordle, in this game your're going to be guessing a random word of 5 letters, if the word have a a correct letters it will tell you, if the letter is in the word but isn't at the place that it's supposed to be it will say that the letter is in the word but ins't at the correct place, and if it ins't at the word it will say nothing.And you only have 6 tries")

    user_name = input("Enter your name:")

    valid_words = ['sweet','shark','about','maybe','tweet','shard','pleat','elder','table','birds','among','share','label','frame','water','earth','winds','empty','audio','pilot','radio','steel','words','chair','drips','mouse','moose','beach','cloud','yours','house','holes','short','small','large','glass','ruler','boxes','charm','tools']

    TheAnswer = random.choice(valid_words)

    print(TheAnswer)

    number_of_guesses = 1

    guessed_correct = False

    while number_of_guesses < 7 and not guessed_correct:
        print('       ')
        TheGuess = input('Enter your guess (it have to be a 5-letter word and not captalied letters):')
        if len(TheGuess) > 5:
            print('word is not acceptable')
        else:
            print('    ')
        for letter in TheGuess:
            if letter == TheAnswer[position]:
                clue += ' V'
            elif letter in TheAnswer:
                clue += ' O'
            else:
                 clue += ' F'
            position += 1
        print(clue)
        if TheGuess == TheAnswer:
            guessed_correct = True
        else:
            guessed_correct = False
            number_of_guesses += 1
        clue = ""

    if guessed_correct:
        print('Congradulations', user_name,', you won and only used', number_of_guesses,'guesses, :D')
    else:
        print(user_name,'Unfortunatealy you usead all your guesses and lost :( . the word was', TheAnswer)
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic here?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Cut & paste it rather than retyping it. Also, which line is line 30?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing `TheAnswer[position]` which basically means if **TheAnswer** is `x` length long, then the `position` should be,

[image: condition]

But since the `position` variable is a local variable of the function, it continuously increases on each guess. Does not get reset on each guess.

Try moving the

```py
position = 0
```

Into top of the while loop.

#### Code,

```py
import random


def Wordle():
    clue = ""
    print("Welcome to Wordle, in this game your're going to be guessing a random word of 5 letters, if the word have a a correct letters it will tell you, if the letter is in the word but isn't at the place that it's supposed to be it will say that the letter is in the word but ins't at the correct place, and if it ins't at the word it will say nothing.And you only have 6 tries")
    user_name = input("Enter your name:")

    valid_words = ['sweet', 'shark', 'about', 'maybe', 'tweet', 'shard', 'pleat', 'elder', 'table', 'birds', 'among', 'share', 'label', 'frame', 'water', 'earth', 'winds', 'empty', 'audio',
                   'pilot', 'radio', 'steel', 'words', 'chair', 'drips', 'mouse', 'moose', 'beach', 'cloud', 'yours', 'house', 'holes', 'short', 'small', 'large', 'glass', 'ruler', 'boxes', 'charm', 'tools']
    TheAnswer = random.choice(valid_words)

    print(TheAnswer)
    number_of_guesses = 1
    guessed_correct = False

    while number_of_guesses < 7 and not guessed_correct:
        position = 0
        print('       ')
        TheGuess = input(
            'Enter your guess (it have to be a 5-letter word and not captalied letters):')
        if len(TheGuess) > 5:
            print('word is not acceptable')
        else:
            print('    ')
        for letter in TheGuess:
            if letter == TheAnswer[position]:
                clue += ' V'
            elif letter in TheAnswer:
                clue += ' O'
            else:
                clue += ' F'
            position += 1
        print(clue)
        if TheGuess == TheAnswer:
            guessed_correct = True
        else:
            guessed_correct = False
            number_of_guesses += 1
        clue = ""

    if guessed_correct:
        print('Congradulations', user_name, ', you won and only used',
              number_of_guesses, 'guesses, :D')
    else:
        print(
            user_name, 'Unfortunatealy you usead all your guesses and lost :( . the word was', TheAnswer)
```

Thanks!